# Assembly does not contain a Web resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, syncfusion

Assembly 'Syncfusion.EJ.Web, Version=14.4450.0.15, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not contain a Web resource with name 'Syncfusion.EJ.Web.Resources.web.ej.pdfviewer.min.js'.

I have been trying t figure this out for the past 2 days and can't find a way to resolve it even after adding assemblies in web.config file.

This is a pdfViewer control from Syncfusion.
Thanks

Comment: Did you add Syncfusion to your project through NuGet or directly by adding DLL's?

Comment: Through NuGet @IzzetYildirim

Comment: Which packages did you add to your project specifically? It is basically says a web resource which is registered in one of the Syncfusion DLL's is not included in the assembly. So you need to find the correct package that includes pdfviewer.min.js file. If you can list your packages I can help you to find the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using Syncfusion products.

This issue will be fixed in Syncfusion Essential Studio 2017 Volume 1 release which will be available at the mid of February 2017.